# How do I have the div displayed without having text content?

Tags: html, css

Im fairly new to CSS and am trying to achieve a full-page width bar. I thus created a class to handle the full page width and want to create separate classes for bars of different colors. However, the browser doesn't render the bar. I've tried to apply `postion:relative` to the main full-width div and `position:absolute` to the bar div to no effect. How can I tackle this problem?
I observed that I can punch the CSS lines into one div to give me the desired effect. However, I wanted to divide the two functionalities into two different classes, just for the sake of trying to write clean code.

```
.fullwidth{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

.bar-1{
        background-color: lightblue;
}

<div class = "fullwidth">
    <div class = "bar-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `min-height`:

```css
.fullwidth{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

.bar-1{
        background-color: lightblue;
        min-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "fullwidth">
    <div class = "bar-1"></div>
</div>
```

Pay attention that the `min-height` and the `font-size` attributes are compatible.

Comment: @AkashSubramanian it would be great if you could mark the answer solved your problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your .bar-1 doesn't seem to have a width or height

```
.bar-1{
    background:lightblue;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ccp3qpb/

Comment: I was expecting the .bar-1 to inherit the height and width property of the .fullwidth class. I was hoping to have a generic dimension for all bars, but just have different colors

Comment: @AkashSubramanian If you want inherited value then use `height: inherit;`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal thank you! I was really thinking in terms of public inheritance from OOP! I had no idea of that CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

U can get the bar by adding some height to your bar... else it will be as 0 pixels and then you won't be able to see it.

```
.bar-1
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    height:20px;
}
```